# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to compile fragment shader

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, tensorflow.js

So I'm using tensorflow JS and python for training models. Now I'm working on the website so that abstract doctors could upload an MRI image and get the prediction. Here's my code:

```
<script>
    async function LoadModels(){  
               model = undefined;
               model = await tf.loadLayersModel("http://127.0.0.1:5500/modelsBrain/modelBrain.json");
               const image = document.getElementById("image");
               const image1 = tf.browser.fromPixels(image);
               const image2 = tf.reshape(image1, [1,200,200,3]);
               const prediction = model.predict(image2);
               const softmaxPred = prediction.softmax().dataSync();
               alert(softmaxPred);

               let top5 = Array.from(softmaxPred)
                    .map(function (p, i) {
                        return {
                            probability: p,
                            className: TARGET_CLASSES_BRAIN[i]
                        };
                    }).sort(function (a, b) {
                        return b.probability - a.probability;
                    }).slice(0, 4);
                    
            const pred = [[]];
            top5.forEach(function (p) {
            pred.push(p.className, p.probability);
            alert(p.className + ' ' + p.probability);
        });
            }

    const fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
    const image = document.getElementById("image");

    function getImage() {
        if(!fileInput.files[0])
        throw new Error("Image not found");
        const file = fileInput.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            const dataUrl = event.target.result;
            const imageElement = new Image();
            imageElement.src = dataUrl;

            imageElement.onload = async function () {
                image.setAttribute("src", this.src);
                image.setAttribute("height", this.height);
                image.setAttribute("width", this.width);
                await LoadModels();
            };
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    fileInput.addEventListener("change", getImage);
</script>
```

This error occurrs not every (!) Live Server open. I am confused, what seems to be the problem?

[image]

Comment: a) you're not handling errors in your code b) there has been an exception in tensorflow

Comment: @Bergi thank you so much. What kind of problem it can be?

Answer (score 3):

Error `CONTEXT_LOST_WEBGL` is 99% due to low GPU memory - what kind of HW do you have available? Alternatively, you can try `WASM` backend which runs computation on CPU and doesn't require GPU resources.

Btw, you're not deallocating your tensors anywhere so if you're running this in a loop for multiple inputs, you do have a massive memory leak. But if error occurs on the first input already, your GPU simply is not good enough for this model.

Comment: Very much thanks! Just `tf.setBackend("cpu")` solved my problem. This post ended me a whole day debugging.